# d3 transitions not working in multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My question has to do with [this chart](https://gf.neocities.org/co2bs/co2bee.html) (Beeswarm plot). I have a project which is based on this more or less. Some things are different and the volume of data is a little higher. For some reason, I don't see any transitions in IE, Firefox or Edge when the chart is updated with new data; however it works perfectly in chrome.

When I click on the filters to update the data, there is a 2-4 second lag and the new data is reflected after that. There is no transition but more like a graph refresh.

The exact browser versions are as follows:

```
Chrome v56 [Works]
Firefox v51
IE v11.576
Edge v38
```

Does any one have any idea about what might be causing this? Thanks in advance

Note: The example I used to make this chart works on IE, Firefox and Edge.

Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rfvfnvdL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lag can be easily explained. You forgot to change this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; ++i) simulation.tick();
```

In my original code I had approximately 190 countries. However, you have 440 data points, and that takes more time to compute.

Thus, simply change the number of calls to `tick` to something between 100 and 300:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 150; ++i) simulation.tick();
//                   ^-------- tweak this number
```

The greater this number the smaller the chance of overlapping circles, but the greater the lag. In a "normal" D3 force directed chart with the default settings, `tick` runs 300 times before the simulation stops.

If you want to keep the ticks as `dataset.lenght`, introducing a `delay` in the transitions reduces the visual effect of the lag.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oo20pdnk/

Regarding the other browsers, I couldn't reproduce the problem: It is working in Firefox and IE to me. However, you have some jQuery code at the bottom (which I removed anyway, mixing D3 with jQuery gives me headache).

PS: When using someone else's code, I believe it's a good idea changing the variable names. Right now you have something like `africaColor`, `europeColor`, `countriesCircles` etc, which makes sense in my code, but not in yours!

Comment: Thank you Gerardo, playing with the `i` value and introducing delays alleviated the problem. and Yes, I do need to refactor the code, including variable names. I was more occupied trying to make it work with my data first.

Comment: On a separate note, great work on this graph. This is a very cool visualization.

Comment: Thanks. Another solution is moving the circles in each tick, as regular force directed charts do. That would greatly reduce the delay.